# Exponential Inequality For Probability of Being Close to Maximum

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, extreme-value

Given $n$ independent identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ that have $|X_i| < \lambda$ for all $i$. Let $\max(X)$ be the maximum of these $n$ variables.

Is there a upper bound on $P[\max(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) - X_i < \epsilon]$ in terms of $\lambda, N$ and $\epsilon$. I was hoping the probability would be exponential i.e. something of order $e^{-n}$.

Comment: Since you no longer use an expression in the form `\max(X)` after you defined it  (you instead list the elements in the later use of $\max$), you might be able to omit the second sentence without harming your question.

Comment: There's no reason to expect any such relation to hold in such generality.  Are you perhaps also assuming the $X_i$ are *identically distributed?*

Comment: Yes they are all from the same distribution.